# PDF generator functionality/utility in snowflake

Tags: pdf, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

currently we are using SQR to generate the PDF report in Exadata. We are planning to migrate from Exadata to Snowflake but wanted to know if there are any utilities similar to SQR or any other features to generate PDF report using snowflake?

I would really appreciate your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the External functions are helping here. With External functions you can call a procedure that executes outside Snowflake (e.g. on AWS Lambda)

Advandage: Code can be written in languages that regular don't support (e.g. Python, Go, C#, ...) and you can use functions/libraries that can't be accessed inside Snowflake (e.g. a pdf-generation library)

More infos can be seen here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html

Another hint for the future is the recently announced feature "Snowpark". Snowpark is kind of a new and extended development environment for Snowflake which is only available in test environments for now: https://www.snowflake.com/news/snowflake-announces-new-features-to-mobilize-the-worlds-data-in-the-data-cloud/

Comment: Thanks for your input. we are going to use Azure Data lake(ADL) to interact with snowflake. will check if we can create PDF report using external functions.